# Making .exe file in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, exe, sfml

I have made my project in C++ and used SFMl 2.1, I also have loaded images from disk and when I'm trying to run its .exe file its giving error in image loading. 
For now I'm trying to run its own .exe fie (in Debug or Release folder of project).

i want to make this .exe file for my friends who are not programmers so that my game would run on their PCs as well.
If someone know to make .exe so please help!

Comment: also worth noting is that anybody who doesn't have Visual Studio 2013 installed needs the Visual C++ 2013 runtime installed to run any C++ program compiled with VS2013.

Comment: @peterT That is only the case if you link dynamically to the C++ runtime (/MD and /MDd compiler options). If you link statically to the runtime (/MT and /MTd compiler options) then the output will not have any dependency on the runtime. Also, the end-user does not need to install the runtime - you can deploy the application with the necessary DLLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to put the images beside the exe file.

After that, your friends probably won't have all the development DLL and libs needed for your app to work. You can use [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to know what is needed for your app to start. Put all those file beside your exe and it should work on most PCs.

### Bonus tip

Often, when you experience this kind of problem (application crash when starting directly outside the project), the simplest solution, which is language-agnostic, is to make your app write to a new file within your main function and look where it ends up in your project hierarchy after you ran your app directly (outside the IDE/project).

You'll see right there where the relative root of your app is. Most of the time, it's right next to the compiled file, depending on the language you chose.

Comment: I put all files beside .exe file and its working fine now, and for .dll files I linked SFML statically . (:

Comment: I added a bonus tip, useful for every new project, with every new language.